# What is this effect called in music?

Tags: effects

At 0:26 it starts and ends in 0:33. It goes through the entire song and that I what I like with that song. What is this typoe of background music called? I very much like it.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking about. Electronic drum sound? Timing? Lo fi hip hop genre?

Comment: Sounds like lo-fi music

Comment: I like the song too, but I have no idea which quality of the song you mean when you say “this effect.” I can hear that the song briefly goes silent and then changes significantly at 0:26; I don’t hear any change at all at 0:33.

Comment: Perhaps OP means the way that the background ‘breathy’ pad sound _bends_ up to the notes each time?